# Implement a welcome message in django-allauth after activating the account

Tags: django-allauth

I want to send an email welcome message to my users after they activated their accounts. Unfortunately there is no such signal. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html You are going to have to be a little more clear why none of these work for you. It wouldn't be that hard to keep track of the first login.

Comment: How would you track the first login? Create for that purpose a new model and store if the users has already logged in? (Sound a bit over the top for me)